# How to Convert Arrays element (images) to Bitmap?

Tags: java, android

I want to load images with big size, but i have problem to make it. it Crashes, because OutOfMemoryError. here is my array :

```
Integer[] img = {
R.drawble.pic1, R.drawble.pic2, R.drawble.pic3, R.drawble.pic4
};
```

how to convert img[0],img[1],img[2] and img[3] to bitmap?
Please help.. Sorry my bad english.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html. check this topic. `recycle` or scale down your image.

Comment: @Raghunandan : i've tried some tuts for converting images to bitmap. but i can't make it from element array.

Comment: Android has problems loading large images. Take a look at the article [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you'll convert an array of ids into an array of `Bitmap`:

```
    Integer[] img = { R.drawble.pic1, R.drawble.pic2, R.drawble.pic3,
            R.drawble.pic4 };

    Bitmap[] bitmap = new Bitmap[img.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < img.length; i++)
        bitmap[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), img[i]);
```

If you have problems to convert big size image take a look at [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check here: http://developer.android.com/training/building-graphics.html

and the class BitmapFactory: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

Android apps have a limited heap size (minimum on old devices is as little as 16MB). This varies per device, so be careful during QA. Since a bitmap can take as much as 4 bytes per pixel, large bitmaps can easily fill up your heap (1000 x 1000 pixels = 3.8MB)

What this means is that you have to be very careful and use several tactics to avoid wasting memory:

1. Don't load all the bitmaps at the same time to memory. If you're showing them for example in a `ViewPager` you can load only 1-2 pages at a time. When a page is hidden, destroy its bitmap and call `bitmap.recycle()` to make sure the memory is freed immediately.
2. If the bitmap is larger than your screen size, you can scale it down to save memory. The technique [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) will let you load it initially reduced by 2/3/4.. If you need more fine-tuning, you can load it full size and then rescale using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`. Just don't forget to `recycle()` the original large bitmap immediately.
3. Make sure to explore your app's memory usage by using memory inspection tools such as [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) or `Eclipse MAT`. I recommend to do most explorations on Android 4+ since 2.x saved bitmaps in the native heap which can't be explored easily. If you can keep your app under 16MB peak memory consumption, you should never hit an OutOfMemoryError again.